# RCD snubber vs active clamp

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Consider an isolated Flyback SMPS with RCD snubber on the primary side MOSFET's drain. As the drain voltage rises above the sum of input voltage and snubber capacitor voltage, the diode opens and conducts the leakage energy into the capacitor.

The same happens with an active clamp circuit, the only difference is that the diode is replaced with a MOSFET. But where is the resistor? Why is it needed in the RCD version and not in the active clamp?

Comment: Post a circuit showing the differences.

Comment: The RCD snubber dissipates much of the leakage energy in the resistor.  The idea of the active clamp is to NOT dissipate as much energy as possible, and instead return it to the source for higher efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But where is the resistor? Why is it needed in the RCD version and not
>   in the active clamp?

In the passive clamp, once the capacitor has stored the excess energy from the flyback transformer's primary leakage inductance, the diode that feeds the capacitor becomes reverse biased and hence the capacitor remains charged (unless a discharge path is provided). If a resistor wasn't added in parallel with the capacitor it would remain charged and the voltage on that capacitor would "staircase" up over several switching cycles to a point where it no longer provided protection for the switching MOSFET and the MOSFET would die.

For this reason, a discharge path is provided in the form of a parallel resistor hence, the excess energy is burnt off.

With an active clamp, the added MOSFET is used to both route the excess energy into the capacitor (as per a passive clamp) and then return it to the primary inductance and thus, the energy is conserved.

Comment: So the only difference is, that in case of active clamp, the current can flow in both directions during the main switch off time and that's why the voltage doesn't "staircase" up, right?

Comment: Correct correct.

Comment: If I would like to calculate the clamp capacitor voltage, how should I start? All I could find in papers are the results for the selection of C and R values, but no one has explained how he got it, so I would like to find the equations by myself.

Comment: The peak capacitor voltage is dictated by the leakage inductance energy which in turn is dictated by the primary current flow at the end of the first half of the switching cycle. Calculate energy stored in the leakage inductor and equate it to energy stored in the capacitor and that tells you the voltage. Do you know those energy equations?

Comment: Of course. With those I get \$ U=I_{peak} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} \$. But this view of the problem implies that the capacitor is fully discharged and then charged back to max voltage during the cycles, although I read that its voltage should not change significantly.

Comment: If the voltage did not change significantly, then it wouldn’t be doing a very good job of returning energy to the primary. Maybe you are thinking of the average voltage.

Comment: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-4147.pdf
On page 3, the first section under Snubber design says: "It is assumed that the snubber capacitance is  large  enough  that  its  voltage  does  not change  during  one switching period."

Comment: I think it has to be a mistake because for an RCD snubber it will charge from a lowish voltage (the remnant left by the previous discharge by Rsn) to the peak voltage we have previously talked about. This error is further seen in the graph for Vsn - it clearly doesn't hold constant yet it is the voltage across Csn and Rsn. Normally in switcher analysis, a statement like that is reserved for the main output capacitor across Vo. I think there are mistakes here.